# Prevent ReferenceError in multi-page dash application

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing a `multi-page` dash application. My project structure is as below:

```
- project/
  - pages/
     - home.py
     - graph.py
  - app.py
  - index.py
```

On `app.py` page, I have a theme switch button. The app gets loaded, When I change the theme color, The theme gets reflected on the current page. But I am getting an error as below

```
ReferenceError: A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback. The id of this object is `some_component` and the property is `some_property`. The string ids in the current layout are:
[some ids]
```

It looks like that due to the change theme which is also `input` in `graph.py` and its callback is getting triggered even though the page is not loaded.

I have used

```
prevent_initial_call=True, In callbacks
suppress_callback_exceptions=True, In dash constructor and
I tried try-catch block but fail to catch exception, for eg in graph.py

if triggered_id == "some_id":
  try:
    some code
  except Exception:
    raise PreventUpdate
```

But I am still getting the error. Is there way to avoid this or catch this exception?

Comment: Could be your Dash version (https://community.plotly.com/t/suppress-callback-exceptions/55623). And you said you're setting the `supress_callback_exceptions = True` ? (`app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True`)

Comment: Hi  russhoppa, Thanks. Yes, I am setting this inside `dash` constructor. I tried many ways to catch that exception using `try except` but always fail to catch it, seems we cannot catch it. and dash version is `'2.9.2'`

Comment: You might get better responses if you post in the [Plotly's community forum](https://community.plotly.com/) I think I've seen some similar problems brought up there. Might be worth a try. Are you seeing the error while running in debug mode or when deployed? In the worst-case scenario, you can add a CSS file to your app that hides the icon associated with the error.